# How to subtract number in where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables,

`tab1`

[image]

`tab2`

[image]

I want to make a result with condition `number` from `tab1` are more than 1, and then the result of `number` from `tab2` are substracted with one.
I have try this code,

```
SELECT T1.users AS UsrT1, T1.number AS NumT1, T2.users AS UsrT2, T2.number AS NumT2, T2.number - 1 AS NumT2_Min_1 
FROM tab1 T1 INNER JOIN tab2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
WHERE T1.number > 1
```

and it's shown like this

[image]

but I want to make a result something like this

[image]

how can I get the result like that? I think like this

```
SELECT T1.users AS UsrT1, T1.number AS NumT1, T2.users AS UsrT2, T2.number AS NumT2_Min_1 
FROM tab1 T1 INNER JOIN tab2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
WHERE (T1.number > 1) - 1
```

but it is totally an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to filter the *calculated value*(`numt2_min_1`). Do the filtration in `Outer query`

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT T1.users      AS UsrT1, 
                T1.number     AS NumT1, 
                T2.users      AS UsrT2, 
                T2.number     AS NumT2, 
                T2.number - 1 AS NumT2_Min_1 
         FROM   tab1 T1 
                INNER JOIN tab2 T2 
                        ON T1.id = T2.id) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  numt2_min_1 > 1
```

or simply

```
SELECT T1.users      AS UsrT1, 
       T1.number     AS NumT1, 
       T2.users      AS UsrT2, 
       T2.number     AS NumT2, 
       T2.number - 1 AS NumT2_Min_1 
FROM   tab1 T1 
       INNER JOIN tab2 T2 
               ON T1.id = T2.id 
WHERE  T2.number - 1 > 1
```

Comment: I'm looking for a whole day and you solve this like, 3 minutes? I'm really look stupid hahaha XD thanks.